# Latin for one who doesn't believe in unicorns?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

What word could we use to describe someone who doesn't believe in unicorns? Ideally, looking for a (newly made or existing) Latin-based word.

Answer (score 6):

**amonocerista**

*a*- is the alpha privative, which denotes absence.

[*μονόκερως*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Dmono%2Fkerws) (*monokeros*) is the Greek word for [unicorn](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/106/does-the-bible-mention-unicorns).

For the ending, the Greeks use -*ιστης* (like in [*οἰκιστής*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Doi)kisth%2Fs)), which in Latin is *ista*.

In English, the word could be simply "amonocerist."

Comment: Do you know of any examples of alpha privative being used to mean "doesn't believe in X"?

Comment: @brianpck You mean besides *atheos*?

Comment: @brianpck Also, I don't think you parsed it right. It's not that the alpha privative means that, but rather it's the conjunction of the alpha and the ending that does it. This word is based on the exact same coinage as "atheist."

Comment: Can you add that explanation to the answer itself? Explicit comparison with "atheist" and other attested derivations would make the case stronger. As it stands, it's all too easy to parse it as @brianpck and I did.

Comment: *atheos* is a great parallel, though I wonder how much the point can be generalized, especially to Latin. The problem is that that example doesn't support your a-X-ista construction: neither Greek nor Latin uses atheista. So, I think you'd either have to propose a-monoceros or find another parallel. (At least on the evidence proposed so far--my gut agrees with your proposal.)

Comment: @brianpck The OP never asked for *Classical* Latin. I assumed, since they mentioned modern coinages, that Neo-Latin, which used and still uses the suffix in abundance [[proof](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/5319/atheista-atheistae)], suffices.

Comment: I also don't think we can take from *atheos* and make *amonoceros*, since in Classical Greek *atheos* is less "atheist" and more "godless." It made better sense in a pre-Christian religious context where "belief" isn't a talking point.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I think that's right about *atheos* being particular--so I guess I'm just returning to my original question of whether you have a good a-X-ista example. "Atheist" seems to come pretty clearly to neo-Latin via French/English.

Comment: @brianpck I can't see the issue. Since this is not Classical Latin, and Neo-Latin admits this construction, then it should work. Plenty of words in Neo-Latin defy Classical construction. The type of question OP is asking suggests he is not looking to see what Cicero would have written.